# Dynamic colors based on content with AMP

Tags: amp-html

I created a Ghost blog recently and a core part of the design of the blog is a background color that changes depending on the title of a blog post. [Here's a live demo](https://blog.canh.am/why-you-should-forget-your-mothers-maiden-name/).

The way that I generate this color currently is by hashing the post title to get a value for the hue (between 0 and 360), which I then use to change the background color with: `hsl(HASH_VALUE, 100%, 93%)`. When the page renders Javascript applies this color to the correct elements on the page.

Given that with AMP I can no longer have my JS code run to accomplish this styling on render, how might I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You must "mimic" the functionality with your server side language.

Example with PHP:

Calculate the hash value in a variable and since you only apply the color to the `header` Do something like this:

```
<header style="background-color:hsl(<?php echo $HASH_VALUE; ?>, 100%, 93%)">
```

NOTE:
It will be faster changing the colors at the back end anyhow than with JS.

Comment: A limitation of Ghost is that I am not able to generate values like this on the backend (as far as I am aware). Are there any other alternative ways that you have seen this done?

Comment: Must be done on the backend. Surely Ghost must allow you to fetch the current post title and generate a hash. Alternatevly, specify a custom property like post_color in your db / dashboard.